# Error running SonarQube console with brew on Mac

Tags: macos, jvm, sonarqube

I am trying to run `/usr/local/opt/sonarqube/bin/sonar console` but getting following error:

> wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
> jvm 1    | WrapperManager: Initializing...
> jvm 1    | WrapperManager: ERROR - The version of the Wrapper which launched this JVM is "3.5.48"
> jvm 1    | WrapperManager:         while the version of the Wrapper jar file currently in use
> jvm 1    | WrapperManager:         is "3.5.49".
> jvm 1    | WrapperManager:
> jvm 1    | WrapperManager: ERROR - The version of the Wrapper which launched this JVM is
> jvm 1    | WrapperManager:         "3.5.48" while the version of the native library
> jvm 1    | WrapperManager:         is "3.5.49".
> jvm 1    | WrapperManager:
> wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same issue and it is now resolved by reinstalling sonarqube.

`brew reinstall -s sonarqube`